# I would like to download only the changelog file of debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-12.04, packaging, debian-based

In debian/ubuntu systems is there any way to download only the changelog file of certian debian package

```
e.g. apt-get download-changelog ls
```

It needs to download the changelog file of the ls package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for apt-listchanges utility

http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/aptlistchanges.htm

Comment: thanks but do you have any other built in command as apt-listchanges is not installed by default

Comment: if it is an installed package and it has changelog, it is probably installed in /usr/share/doc/PACKAGENAME/changelog.gz or changelog.Debian.gz ( depending which changelog you actually want to see. Otherwise, you need to download package first anyway ( e.g. with aptitude or "apt-get source", or look on the web, e.g. http://packages.debian.org/changelogs/pool/